# Cannot iterate through the attributes of an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes, instance-variables

I want to access the value of the `document_id` value in the DocumentUser instance variable and add it to an array. However, while the function `ids` is defined and I can access the `id` value with it, there is no function `document_ids` defined for this class. I could go ahead and define it, but my question is - can I access the `document_ids` value without doing that, perhaps by somehow using the `map` function (which confuses me)? I thought I could iterate through the model since it looks like it returns an Array, but no dice. Thanks!

```
[110] pry(#<#<Class:0x00007f99646b1b60>>)> @current_user.document_users.each { |n| puts n }
#<DocumentUser:0x00007f9957cce118>
=> [#<DocumentUser:0x00007f9957cce118
  id: 382,
  user_id: 26638,
  document_id: 282,
  created_at: Wed, 08 May 2019 15:05:42 CDT -05:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 08 May 2019 15:05:42 CDT -05:00>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be this:

```
@current_user.document_users.map(&:document_id)
```

which is a shorthand of this:

```
@current_user.document_users.map { |document_user| document_user.document_id }
```

Since it's probably `ActiveRecord` class, it's even better way to achieve this result, using `pluck`:

```
@current_user.document_users.pluck(:document_id)
```